# How do I access json data with changing property from the array. JS-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, api

Please accept my advance apologies if this is very simple. I just started learning js.

I am building a school project and using holiday API. When using just the country and year, JSON data that I get is like this one below.

My problem is, since the dates in bold changes depending on the search parameters of country and year, I am not sure how to access them to show them on my page.

**JSON DATA1**

```
"status": 200,
    "holidays": {
        **"2016-01-01":** [{
            "name": "Last Day of Kwanzaa",
            "date": "2016-01-01",
            "observed": "2016-01-01",
            "public": false
        }, {
            "name": "New Year's Day",
            "date": "2016-01-01",
            "observed": "2016-01-01",
            "public": true
        }],
```

I saved this as json file to use for my testing. Below is the code I was using to try accessing the json data above.

```
const $list = $(`<ul>`);
$("#output").append($list)
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    const holiday = data.holidays;

    if (data.holidays.hasOwnProperty ('name'));
        console.log('name' in data.holidays);

    if (data.cod == 200) {
        $list.html("Success");
    }
    data.holidays.forEach((item) => {
        $list.append(`<tr><td><li style="font-weight: bold">Holiday: ${item.name}</li><li>Date: ${item.date}</li><li>Date observed: ${item.observed}</li></td></tr>`);    
    });
```

The code above works if my parameters include country, year and month since data that comes from that call is like the one below.

**JSON DATA2**

```
"holidays": [{
        "name": "Pearl Harbor Remembrance Day",
        "date": "2016-12-07",
        "observed": "2016-12-07",
        "public": false
    }, {
        "name": "Immaculate Conception of the Virgin Mary",
        "date": "2016-12-08",
        "observed": "2016-12-08",
        "public": false
    },
```

I want to be able to display my JSON DATA1 to my html. How do I do it when the date property are not static like the name, date, observed and public?

Below is the error I get with my current code:

> script.js:125 Uncaught TypeError: data.holidays.forEach is not a function
>           at Object.success (script.js:125)
>           at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
>           at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
>           at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
>           at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use only a `forEach` in this case because `holidays` is not an array, but a standard object with the dates as properties. The loop type you have to use is [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). It lets you iterate over the enumerable properties of an object.

For example:

```
for (holiday in data.holidays) {
  data.holidays[holiday].forEach((item) => {
    $list.append(`<tr><td>` +
      `<li style="font-weight: bold">Holiday: ${item.name}</li>` +
      `<li>Date: ${item.date}</li>` +
      `<li>Date observed: ${item.observed}</li>` +
      `</td></tr>`);
  }
});
```

I haven't tested the code above in a browser, only with console.logs in Node.